# Convert GCC's __builtin_ia32_pshufd and __v4si mode to portable intrinsic?

Tags: c, gcc, intrinsics

I have a program filled with custom macros and GCC intrinsics like `__builtin_ia32_pshufd`. I'd like to convert it to Intel intrinsics for portabiltiy and eventual Windows support.

I preprocessed the source file, including the `-fno-builtin` option, but I seem to be getting some builtins. Here's one of them:

```
row = 
 ((__m128i)__builtin_ia32_pshufd ((__v4si)(__m128i)(
 row
 ), (int)((((
 1
 ) << 6) | ((
 0
 ) << 4) | ((
 3
 ) << 2) | (
 2
 )))))
 ;
```

I'm also having trouble figuring out what to do with the mode attribute (`__v4si`):

```
row = 
 ((__m128i) ((__v4si)(__m128i)(
 row
 ), (int)((((
 0
 ) << 6) | ((
 3
 ) << 4) | ((
 2
 ) << 2) | (
 1
 )))))
 ;
```

How do I convert these two GCC intrinsics into a portable, Intel intrinsic?

Comment: @Olaf - Nothing needs editing. Please develop some subject matter knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
row = 
 ((__m128i) ((__v4si)(__m128i)(
 row
 ), (int)((((
 0
 ) << 6) | ((
 3
 ) << 4) | ((
 2
 ) << 2) | (
 1
 )))))
 ;
```

This can be returned to a portable intrinsic with:

```
row = (_mm_shuffle_epi32(row, _MM_SHUFFLE(2,1,0,3)));
```

If you are working with a preprocessed source file, then:

```
file=<preprocessed source file>
tfile=<temporary file>

cp $file $tfile

sed -i 's|(__m128i)__builtin_ia32_pshufd ((__v4si)(__m128i)|_mm_shuffle_epi32(|g' "$tfile"

perl -0777 -i -pe 's/\(\n 0\n\)/0/igs' "$tfile"
perl -0777 -i -pe 's/\(\n 1\n\)/1/igs' "$tfile"
perl -0777 -i -pe 's/\(\n 2\n\)/2/igs' "$tfile"
perl -0777 -i -pe 's/\(\n 3\n\)/3/igs' "$tfile"
perl -0777 -i -pe 's/\(\n row\n\)/ row/igs' "$tfile"

sed -i 's|(int)(((2 << 6) \| (1 << 4) \| (0 << 2) \| 3)))|_MM_SHUFFLE(2,1,0,3))|g' "$tfile"
sed -i 's|(int)(((1 << 6) \| (0 << 4) \| (3 << 2) \| 2)))|_MM_SHUFFLE(1,0,3,2))|g' "$tfile"
sed -i 's|(int)(((0 << 6) \| (3 << 4) \| (2 << 2) \| 1)))|_MM_SHUFFLE(0,3,2,1))|g' "$tfile"
...
```

Comment: You don't need to use `_MM_SHUFFLE`.  It's certainly easier to read than that mess, but the original still produces an integer that you can use as the shuffle arg to `_mm_shuffle_epi32`.  Another semi-readable way to write 1,0,3,2 without the `_MM_SHUFFLE` macro is `0b01001110`.  I prefer the 0b way in assembler, but in C the `_MM_SHUFFLE` way is preferable.